# Code coverage for service class method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, code-coverage

I'm trying to do the code coverage for a method of service class with mockito. I'm new with mockito and tried to mock the call to service method but the code coverage is 0. I'm not sure if I can mock call or can I for this particular method. If you have any suggestions please let me know.
Code:

```
public List<Something> getTrackerData(String startDay,List<Something> someList,  boolean check,String name)
{
//filled with many if else checks
}
```

This is the method i want to do coverage for.

@InjectMocks
    private TrackerService trackerService;

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
    public void test01()
    {
        Something ttd =new Something();
        ttd.setCoverageSubType("None");
        ttd.setCoveredAmount("1.0");
        List<Something> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(ttd);

        List<Something > newlist = mock(List.class);
//      when(trackerService.getTrackerData("", newlist, false, "")).
//      thenReturn(list);

        resultList = trackerService.getTrackerData(anyString(), anyList(), anyBoolean(), anyString());

    }
```

This is the test i have written. I realize that when and Mockito.verify() works only on mocked dependencies. But here I don't have any dependency to mock. So, the question is can I mock the call to `trackerService.getTrackerData()` with Mockito stub parameters or I have to test the method with actual parameters only ?

Comment: For it to work you need to swap the actual parameters in the call to `Mockito.when` with the stub ones. And thenn call the actual service (in your snippet the last line) with some test parameters

Comment: so this will be the only way right ?

Comment: That is the right way. What you're currently doing is, what I would say, a wrong use of mockito

Comment: Yeah I know that, but the thing is I want to see if I can call the method without passing exact parameters as that will consume a lot of time.

Comment: to be clear, you're trying to get code coverage on a method that you are trying to mock?

Comment: @PhilNinan yes, but I'm not sure if I can get coverage for a mocked method as call won't even reach to the actual method. Is there any way I can get the coverage for the method without passing actual parameters ?

Comment: That is correct, you will not get coverage on a mock. A mock sets up a proxy class, therefore the original class will NEVER be called. It seems to be that you should NOT mock "trackerService". Is there any reason you feel the need to mock it?

Comment: @PhilNinan No I don't feel like mocking the service. All i want to achieve is call the service method without passing actual parameters for code coverage.

Answer (score 1):

TrackerService is already using InjectMocks. So you simply can use Mockito.when().

```
List<Something> result = new ArrayList();
//populate list
Mockito.when(trackerService.getTrackerData(anyString(), anyList(), anyBoolean(), anyString())).thenReturn(result);
```

Comment: But don't I have to @Mock  "trackerService" because when only accepts mocked dependencies, and If I do that  there won't be any real call to getTrackerData() method.

Comment: Try using with @spy annotation instead of injectMocks